# IIS WebApp: slow Windows-Authentication in other Windows-Domain

Tags: windows, web, iis, webserver, windows-authentication

I have a problem with IIS Windows authentication. I have a client in windows domain A and a server (IIS) in windows domain B (trust-relationship).
The client has an A domain user logged in (A\user01). If the user calls a web page of the server in domain B, the first call takes about 15 to 20 seconds. Subsequent calls are fast (well under 1s).
If I call the same page from a client of domain B with a user from this (B\user02), the page load is directly fast.
Does anyone have an idea what this could be due to?

I have already tried the following:

- Looked at the waterfall model in the Edge browser dev tools => Connection start - Delayed: 15.09s.
- Application Pool => Startup mode set to "AlwaysRunning", Idle time-out increased, Idle time-out action set to "Suspend".
- Anonymous authentication enabled => problem that I don't recognize the logged in user in PHP variables anymore.
- Set up a second web server in domain A with ARR and Rewrite module as ReverseProxy to use it for authentication => Unfortunately, it does not work as I thought it would.

Comment: Escalate that to the domain administrators and they can review the settings for you, about foreign security principals.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.